# how to get input data before submitting the form?

Tags: php, mysqli

Is this possible? Been searching about it but didn't find a solution specifically for my problem. When the user input in textbox1 and textbox2, I want to get the inputs of both textboxes before he submit the form. because in my php file, i am going to do a condition wherein the logic is like

```
if ($inputFromTextbox1=='Hi' && $inputFromTextbox2 == 'Beautiful'{
    $insertToDB == 'She is nice';
} else {
    $insertToDB == 'She is not nice';
}
```

The `$insertToDB` is another variable I use to insert in another column in my database. `$inputFromTextbox1` and `$inputFromTextbox2` also have their respective columns. Help anyone? I hope you understood my question.

Comment: Well, you certainly can't get the data *server-side* until it's actually *posted to the server*.  It's not really clear what you're trying to do here.  If you just want to do some client-side UX changes before submitting the form, do those in JavaScript.

Comment: If you want to do something with those values in PHP, then you have to send them to the server first – meaning, you have to make an HTTP request. If you do not want to submit the form, then you can use AJAX to make that request. (But _why_ do you want to send those values _before_ you submit the form anyway? If you only need them to decide what to insert into the database – that decision could as well be made after the whole form is send, normally.)

Comment: You can use javascript/jQuery for that.

Comment: PHP is a server-side language. So if you need to get the form value before submitting, you need to do it at front end. Normally you should use javascript or jQuery to do such work.

Comment: The condition actually takes place during the process of submitting the form. I guess I was confuse because I wanted the result from the condition to be inserted in database together with the other inputs. Sorry this is so confusing.  I hope I can explain better than this. But thank you to everyone who replied and give their suggestions. @CBroe

Answer (score 1):

Well, php is know as one of the existing server side languages, and you cant get things during the execution time on the client. You will only be able to capture inputs when the data reachs the server through one of the http [methods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POST_%28HTTP%29). 
So i would recommend you to use some client side language, javascript, jquery, angular or something like that.